# How to use the site's masterpage from a _layout SharePoint page?

Tags: sharepoint, layout, master-pages

I want to use a masterpagefile (the site's one if this makes sense) in my SharePoint 12 hive/template/layouts/TelephoneBookList/test.aspx file. However, whenever I add MasterPageFile="~/_layouts/simple.master" or something like that to my test.aspx page, I get a sharepoint error page and the following in the log file:

01/12/2009 10:56:26.95  w3wp.exe (0x1064)                           0x1280  Windows SharePoint Services     Topology                        0   Critical    Invalid URL: http://localhost.  You may also need to update any alternate access mappings referring to http://mcdevsp.  Help on this error: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=114854

01/12/2009 10:56:27.09  w3wp.exe (0x1064)                           0x1280  Windows SharePoint Services     General                         8dzz    High        Exception Type: System.Web.HttpException  Exception Message: The file '/_layouts/TelephonebookList/~masterurl/default.master' does not exist.

01/12/2009 10:56:27.23  w3wp.exe (0x1064)                           0x1280  Windows SharePoint Services     Topology                        0   Critical    Invalid URL: http://localhost.  You may also need to update any alternate access mappings referring to http://mcdevsp.  Help on this error: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=114854

01/12/2009 10:56:27.70  w3wp.exe (0x1064)                           0x1280  Windows SharePoint Services     General                         8dzw    Medium      spHttpHandler:GetHash started

01/12/2009 10:56:27.70  w3wp.exe (0x1064)                           0x1280  Windows SharePoint Services     General                         8dzx    Medium      spHttpHandler:GetHash finished

Without the MasterPageFile attributes, it works perfectly, however it does not have the global Look & Feel of the web site.

Many thanks.

Comment: What class do you use for test.aspx?

Comment: Class, hm? it's just a page that starts with:

<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/_layouts/simple.master" Inherits="..my custom code.." %>

<%@ Register Tagprefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" 
   Assembly=".." %>

<!DOCTYPE html ..

my cust. code is in a DLL in GAC

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

Leave the MasterPageFile declaration at it's default (~/_layouts/simple.master) and override OnPreInit in your custom code.

```
protected override void OnPreInit(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPreInit(e);

    this.MasterPageFile = SPContext.Current.Web.MasterUrl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint requires _layouts pages to be declared with ~/_layouts/application.master. The OnPreInit technique can then be used to change the master at runtime.

An HttpModule can be used to change the master on all application pages: [How to customise the SharePoint application.master file](http://stephenkaye.blogspot.com/2008/03/how-to-customise-applicationmaster-file.html)